# Angular materials change md-radio-button color

Tags: angular-material

is anybody know how to change `md-radio-button` color in angular materials?

I'm trying to do this in config like that

```
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('orange')
        .accentPalette('orange');
```

But i would prefair do this in css and I want to set exact color to my md-radio-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <md-radio-group>
    <md-radio-button ng-value="green" class="my-radio">
      button
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>

  <style>
      //unchecked
      md-radio-button.my-radio .md-off{
          border-color: blue;
      }
      //checked
      md-radio-button.md-checked.my-radio .md-on{
          background-color: blue;
      }
```

Comment: The asker want to freely set exact colors. Not only blue, green and yellow

Comment: This does not work. You have to append the name of the class after "checked", as follows: 
md-radio-button.md-checked.my-radio .md-on { 
// Define your styles
}

Answer (score 3):

this code will change color of your radio-button:

```
md-radio-button.md-default-theme .md-on, md-radio-button .md-on {
  background-color: rgb(67, 174, 86);
}
md-radio-button.md-default-theme.md-checked .md-off, md-radio-button.md-checked .md-off {
  border-color: rgb(67, 174, 86);
}
```

Comment: This answer works but it will change the style of all the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

check this [Declarative Syntax](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax)

you can set like this

```
 <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
```

you can also set class="md-accent" and class="md-warn"

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't appear to work anymore or doesn't work with chrome.

Svetlana's answer works but isn't doing it for a single radio button with a class and needs an additional !important. For setting an individual radio button's color with a class do this:

```
.green-radio .md-on,
.green-radio md-radio-button .md-on {
    background-color: rgb(67, 174, 86);
}

.green-radio .md-off,
.green-radio md-radio-button.md-checked .md-off {
    border-color: rgb(67, 174, 86) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the radio button as follows:
In the template, you can provide the class name

```
<md-radio-button class="my-class" value="Orange">
    Orange
</md-radio-button>
```

And in the css you can do as follows

```
md-radio-button.md-checked.my-class .md-on {
background-color: blue; 
}

md-radio-button.md-checked.my-class .md-off {
border-color: blue;
}
```

You can work around with it to your liking. If you just want to change the color of the button and not the circular border around it, then you can ignore the code for .md-off class.

I am using and testing it on google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: #007ad9;
    background-color: #007ad9;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button .mat-accent .mat-radio-checked .cdk-focused .cdk-mouse-focused {
    border-color: green;
    background-color: green;
} 

    enter code here

/* //checked */
mat-radio-button.md-checked.my-radio .md-on{
    background-color: blue !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle, .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element:not(.mat-radio-persistent-ripple), .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-persistent-ripple, .mat-radio-button.mat-accent:active .mat-radio-persistent-ripple {
    background-color: white;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition:  ease 280ms;
    width: 20px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: on this site explaining your code is good to do so the person who asked the question also learns